# URL rewrite using htaccess from index.php to index.html

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the url

I used the .htaccess code as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
```

URL is http://www.example.com/dashboard/index.php

And I want to rewrite the url index.php to index.html

can someone give me the idea to rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Comment: Not working. I am working in ubuntu server. I enabled the mod_rewrite. Is there any problem with mod_rewrite enabling

Comment: if its not enabled then it wont work. firstly check using php_info() is it enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Depend where you have your .htaccess file. If it is in your root follder than you will have

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^dashboard/index.html$ /dashboard/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

If you want it to be done as a redirect instead of just a rewrite modify the [L] to [L,R]